# Finding accumulation function given force of interest

Tags: finance

### An investment grows at a force of interest  $\delta(t)= \frac{3\sqrt{t}}{100}$. Calculate the effective annual rate of  interest over $4$ years.

---

$a(t)=e^{\int_0^t \frac{3\sqrt{t}}{100} dt}=e^{\frac{2}{100}t^{\frac{3}{2}}}-1$

$a(4)=e^{\frac{4}{25}}-1$

The answer provided is $a(4)=e^{\frac{1}{25}}-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a(4)=e^{\frac{4}{25}}$

$(1+i)^4=e^{\frac{4}{25}}$

Taking $ln$

$\rightarrow 4\ln{(1+i)}=\frac{4}{25}$

$\ln{1+i}=\frac{1}{25}$

$\therefore i=e^{\frac{1}{25}}-1$